# React Navigation + Redux close App on Back Pressed

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

After converting the app to redux, my `react-navigation` got some problem. Previously, before integrating with redux, when I press back button (Physical button) react-navigation back to the previous screen. After integrating with redux, the back button will close the app. But, it's still working with `goBack()` function.

- I'm following the guide: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux
- And read some code from here : https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/tree/master/examples/ReduxExample

And, this is my Navigator configuration

```
export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
    {
        Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
        ChatDetail: { screen: ChatDetail },
        PulsaDetail: { screen: PulsaDetailScreen },
        Pulsa: { screen: Pulsa }
    },
    {
        headerMode: 'none',
    }
)

class AppWithNavigation extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <AppNavigator navigation={ addNavigationHelpers({
                dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
                state: this.props.nav,
            })} />
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  nav: state.nav
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppWithNavigation)
```

EDIT: It's can be done with manual handle & dispatch back action, but it's can't do it automaticlly? just like before using redux?

```
BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',() => {
    this.props.goBack()
    return true
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After post Github issue in react-navigation repository, I got the answer.

Should add manually the back listener on top of screen / component

```
// App.js
import { BackAndroid } from 'react-native'
// [...]
  componentDidMount() {
    BackAndroid.addEventListener('backPress', () => {
      const { dispatch, nav } = this.props
      if (shouldCloseApp(nav)) return false
      dispatch({ type: 'Back' })
      return true
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackAndroid.removeEventListener('backPress')
  }
// [...]
```

- https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2117
- https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/117

**UPDATE**:

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler

Comment: BackAndroid is deprecated. Use BackHandler instead. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler